# How can I prove this version of the quadratic formula?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field.
Suppose $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\in F[x]$ with  $2a \in F^\times$, and set $\Delta=b^2-4ac$.  Prove the 
following version of the quadratic formula. If there is a $\delta\in F$ such that $\delta^2=\Delta$, then 
$$
\frac{-b\pm \delta}{2a}
$$ 
are  roots of $f(x)$. I am unsure of how to simplify the given form of roots or show that they are actually roots. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since $F$ is a field you have unique factorization in $F[x]$. Hence it suffices to show that $f=a(x-\frac{-b-\delta}{2a})(x-\frac{-b+\delta}{2a})$. To prove this just expand the expression and compare the coefficients using your knowledge of $\delta^2$.